# Stub or Shim Process class with Microsoft Fakes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

I have this code:

Have a method like this:

```
private void Invoke(string executablePathAndFile, string commandLineArguments)
{
    Process process = ProcessInstance;
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = ProcessStartInfo;

    startInfo.FileName = executablePathAndFile;
    startInfo.Arguments = commandLineArguments; 

    process.StartInfo = startInfo;

    process.Start();

    if (WaitForExit)
        process.WaitForExit();
}
```

I am trying to stub or shim out Process class' method calls.  Microsoft Fakes only creates a Stub and not a Shim (not sure why).  I can provide StubProcess in a shimmed out call to ProcessInstanceGet:

```
InvokeExecutableAction sut = new InvokeExecutableAction(actionElement);
StubProcess stubProcess = new StubProcess();
ShimInvokeExecutableAction sutShim = new ShimInvokeExecutableAction(sut)
{
    ProcessInstanceGet = () => stubProcess
};
```

but when the code under test gets to process.Start() , it comes back with a Win32Exception.  I am unable to provide an alternate implementation for the stub's Start method like:

Is there a way to achieve what I need (i.e. provide an alternate execution for Start() method) or refactor the code to be more testable (without going overboard!!!)?

Comment: did you check the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Add this in the XML of system.fakes and not in the XML of mscorlib.fakes

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/">
  <Assembly Name="System" Version="4.0.0.0"/>
  <ShimGeneration>
    <Add FullName="System.Diagnostics"/>
  </ShimGeneration>
</Fakes>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit the System.fakes file as following,  so that it will generate the Shims for System.Diagnostics.Process

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/" Diagnostic="true">
  <Assembly Name="System" Version="4.0.0.0"/>
  <ShimGeneration>
    <Add FullName="System.Diagnostics.Process"/>
  </ShimGeneration>
</Fakes>
```

Possible Duplicate:
[How to use Microsoft Fakes Assemblies on Process.Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18610684/how-to-use-microsoft-fakes-assemblies-on-process-start)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you will have to first add a fakes assembly. `process` class present in `System.dll` and so

> 1.In Solution Explorer, expand your unit test project’s References.
>
> 2.Select the `system.dll` assembly.
>
> 3.On the shortcut menu, choose Add Fakes Assembly.

Then use the shim method instead. A good example can be found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549176.aspx

```
[Test]
public void Y2kCheckerTest() {
  using(ShimsContext.Create()) {
    ShimDateTime.NowGet = () => new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
    Y2KChecker.Check();
  }
}
```

Comment: Correct Rahul, and I did do that but this approach does not seem to work for the Process class.  First of all no shim is created, even if I modify the Fakes XML config file trying to force it's creation.  A stub is created but it doe snot seem to behave as expected as I cannot stub out a call to Start method.